# Making custom types drawable with SFML

Tags: c++, sfml

I picked up using SFML recently, and I decided as a learning experience I would make a pong clone using it. I've defined a class called `Ball` which draws uses SFML to draw a `RectangleShape`. When I try to draw this custom type to the screen with the `window.draw()` function however, I get errors because `Ball` isn't an `sf::Drawable`. I would appreciate help with this, being new to SFML.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To use `window.draw(object)` object's class must inherit the [drawable interface](http://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.3.2/classsf_1_1Drawable.php) and implement the abstract sf::Drawable::draw function.

It sounds like the sf::RectangleShape is a member of Ball. SFML knows how to render the shape, but not Ball itself. Ball's class declaration should look like this:

```
class Ball : public sf::Drawable //,...
{
    //...
    private:
    virtual void draw(sf::RenderTarget& target, sf::RenderStates states) const;
    //...
};
```

And draw should be implemented like this:

```
void Ball::draw(sf::RenderTarget& target, sf::RenderStates states) const
{
    //assuming m_shape is the sf::RectangleShape
    target.draw(m_shape, states);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I thought it had to do with inheriting the Drawable class, I just wasn't sure of how to go about doing so.

Comment: @Terrance8D When in doubt, look at the API - one of the many things SFML has going for it is excellent documentation. Hope your project goes well!