# how to pass a attribute into a method of another class

Tags: c++, object, pointers, sfml

I cant get the square to display in my window.
I am trying to do this by passing an attribute which is an object, into another object's method. I do not have any Build time errors.

As you can see in drawer.cpp I am passing the square obj, into the draw method of window.

In main.cpp I have gotten a temporary solution working, it is commented out.

Sorry if my explanation is bad please feel free to message me for more information.
Thanks!!!

drawer.cpp

```
#include "../headers/drawer.hpp"
#include <iostream>

Drawer::Drawer()
{
    sf::RectangleShape square(sf::Vector2f(200.0f, 200.0f));
    
    square.setFillColor(sf::Color::Red);
    
    square.setPosition(20.0f, 20.0f);
}

void Drawer::display(sf::RenderWindow* window)
{
    window->draw(square);
}
```

drawer.hpp

```
#ifndef drawer_hpp
#define drawer_hpp

#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

class Drawer
{
    // Attributes
    sf::RectangleShape square;
    
    // Methods
public:
    Drawer();
    void display(sf::RenderWindow* window);
};

#endif /* drawer_hpp */
```

main.cpp

```
#include "headers/drawer.hpp"
int main()
{
    // creating window
    static const unsigned int height{1000}, width{1500};
    
    sf::RenderWindow window( sf::VideoMode(width, height), "Visual Sorter", sf::Style::Close | !sf::Style::Resize);
    
    // creating drawer
    Drawer squ;
    
    /*
    sf::RectangleShape square(sf::Vector2f(200.0f, 200.0f));
    
    square.setFillColor(sf::Color::Red);
    
    square.setPosition(20.0f, 20.0f);
    */
    
    // program loop
    while (window.isOpen()) {
        sf::Event evnt;
        
        // events
        while (window.pollEvent(evnt)) {
            switch (evnt.type) {
                case sf::Event::Closed:
                    window.close();
                    break;
                    
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
        
        
        //window.draw(squ.square);
        squ.display(&window);
        window.display();
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: With `sf::RectangleShape square(sf::Vector2f(200.0f, 200.0f));`, you create local variable (with same name as your member), so your member is not modified.

Comment: You probably want: `Drawer::Drawer() : square(sf::Vector2f(200.0f, 200.0f)); { square.XXX(); }`

Comment: Recommended: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34458791/making-custom-types-drawable-with-sfml